# canvas and img working in chrome but not firefox

Tags: javascript, canvas, cross-browser

I have searched a few results regarding this issue but none of them works for me, so I am posting here to get some helps. Basically my issue is when I clicked on the generate button, I want the image from canvas to be displayed in a img element. However, the image will show up in chrome but not firefox! Below is my coding...

```
<body onload="onLoad();">
  <canvas id="aimage">Your browser does not support the canvas tag.</canvas>
  <input type="button" value="Generate" onclick="genImage();" />
  <img id="cImg" name="cImg" src="${param.src}" />
 ...
</body>
```

And the javascript...

```
var tcanvas;
var scanvas;
var tcontext;
var imageURL;

function onLoad() {
    tcanvas = document.getElementById("aimage");
    tcontext = tcanvas.getContext("2d");
    scanvas = document.getElementById("cImg");
    imageURL = "${param.src}";
    update();                
}

function update() {
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function () {
        if (image.width != tcanvas.width)
            tcanvas.width = image.width;
        if (image.height != tcanvas.height)
            tcanvas.height = image.height;
        tcontext.clearRect(0, 0, tcanvas.width, tcanvas.height);
        tcontext.drawImage(image, 0, 0, tcanvas.width, tcanvas.height);
    }
    image.crossOrigin = 'anon';
    image.src = imageURL;
}

function genImage() {
    var url = tcanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
    scanvas.crossOrigin = 'anon';
    scanvas.src = url;

    if(scanvas.width > 1000){
      scanvas.width = 1000;
    }
    if(scanvas.height > 1000){
      scanvas.height = 1000;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var scanvas, tcontext, tcanvas;
function genImage() {
    var url = tcanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
    scanvas.src = url;
    if (scanvas.width > 1000) {
        scanvas.width = 1000;
    }
    if (scanvas.height > 1000) {
        scanvas.height = 1000;
    }
}
window.onload = function () {
    tcanvas = document.getElementById("aimage");
    tcontext = tcanvas.getContext("2d");
    scanvas = document.getElementById('cImg');
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        tcontext.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height)
    };
    img.src = "yourImage.jpg";
}
```

Comment: I am using ver24. I have updated my coding, is pretty much similar to yours but still not working for me for some unknown reasons. I have no idea how to debug this as it don't show me any errors.

Comment: try to display that base^$ data in developers console, u may find something useful there..

Comment: The base64 is correctly set to the img upon clicking the button. However, the display is still the original image, any reasons why?

Comment: what exactly you are trying to achieve ?
It would be great if I could see its fiddle.